Can an ESD protective surface cause damage to powered on electronics?
I want to connect bare hard drives which are meant for internal use via a SATA/IDE to USB adapter or something similar. That means that the drives will be operating outside of any sort of casing.
The adapter may be designed in such a way that it requires the drives to rest with the side that has the circuit board exposed on it facing down against the surface they are resting on.
My current plan is to use a grounded anti-static mat which I already have, but I learned that ESD protective surfaces are slightly conductive in order to provide a protective effect, albeit with a very high restistance.
In my prior research I discovered this video by Western Digital on the topic of properly handling hard drives.
They recommend using a grounded ESD protective surface as well, but do not specify whether or not it is safe to power internal hard drives on such a surface or only handle them in their powered-off state.
At the timestamp 1:47 one can see one powered and operating hard drvice that is placed on an ESD protective surface. Its circuitry side is facing up, while all non-powered drives have their curcuitry-side facing down. I want to know if having the circuitry side face up during operation is required or if it is okay to have it face down on the mat during operation as well, as the video does not give any specificaton.
This is my most specific reason for asking this question, but I am interested in whether an ESD protective surface is a good place to rest a powered piece of circuitry on or not in general. If not, what kind of surface would be best to rest powered circuitry on?

TL;DR; depends on the surface, but it's generally fine.
ESD workspaces and mats are generally relatively high resistance for safety reasons (if you touch live mains while touching the mat, the high resistance stops you being electrocuted). They only need to stop the build up of charge and provide a relatively equal potential area, so there is no need for them to be highly conductive.
As a result it is generally perfectly safe powering electronics that are resting on these surfaces as the high resistance shouldn't cause any short circuits.
This is not the case for all surfaces. The mylar foil ESD bags (the ones that look like silvery metal) tend to be much more highly conductive which can cause shorts if they contact exposed components and pins on the device being tested. Therefore don't rest the the device on such ESD bags, instead use a proper ESD work mat/surface.

Wrt. the foil bags - it's "ask me how I know", right?

@MrGerber why is this board bit turning on? Ah.

Since you say it is "generally fine" and "generally perfectly safe" i assume that means there are cases where powering on exposed electronics on an anti-static mat would damage them. assuming i use a proper anti-static mat, what cases are those? what should i look out for to always be on the safe side?

@tinkRR Mainly circuits that rely on very high impedances or are very sensitive - e.g. if you had an amplifier with 10's of Megaohm bias networks, the comparitive resistance of the mat may affect operation. Or if you have very high voltages (10s of kilovolts), it's possible that there will be an appreciable current through the mat that could impact operation. But for your standard run of the mill electronics (PC parts, arduinos, etc) there should be no issues.
